# Clone a remote server to local machine via ssh

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

I am trying to clone entire remote server and I am facing permission issue. I have executed the command

```
ssh "ybala"@emweb.com dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -c | dd of=/home/byk/Documents/bp.img.bz
```

the user **ybala** has root privileges on the server. But still I get

> permission denied

Any suggestions how I could face this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the dd command with `sudo`?

Comment: it says "sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo" when i run with sudo

Comment: Try prefixing the dd command with sudo **and** passing the `-t` option to `ssh`.

Comment: 1) `dd` is overkill here, all you need is `cat`. 2) what do you mean when you say that ybala has root privileges? Is ybala the root account (id==0) or do you mean they have sudo access? 3) Are you really, 100% sure that what you want is an image of the disk? What is your final objective? This might be worth reading: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync

Comment: the problem mainly is the communication from remote to host. I don't care if it is image or zip or any format. and yes ybala has sudo access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to run it with -t option on ssh.

The right command is

```
ssh -t "ybala"@emweb.com 'sudo dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -c | cat' > law.img.gz
```